# AU Semimajor axis accuracy

Tags: orbit

I have used [Kepler's 3rd law](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=keplers%20third%20law&assumption=%7B%22FS%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%7B%22KeplersThirdLaw%22%2C%20%22a%22%7D%7D&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C%20%22keplers%20third%20law%22%7D%20-%3E%20%7B%22Formula%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22KeplersThirdLaw%22%2C%20%22m1%22%7D%20-%3E%221%20solar%20mass%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22KeplersThirdLaw%22%2C%20%22T%22%7D%20-%3E%22365%20days%2C%205%20hours%2C%2059%20minutes%20and%2016%20seconds%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C%20%22KeplersThirdLaw%22%2C%20%22m2%22%7D%20-%3E%221%20earth%20mass%22) to calculate the Semi-Major axis of the Earth I have given it the mass of the objects i.e. the sun (1 **solar mass**) and the Earth and time taken to orbit (365 days, 6 hours, 9 minutes ) but when I minus it 1 AU it gives 9345 kilometers (5807 miles) even when I try to get more accurate results by using 1.0000001124 AU - 92.95 million miles it still gives 9362.7 kilometers (5817.72 miles) thus there is still a tiny difference once compared to the size of the orbit (but I want it to be extremely accurate).

Answer (score 7):

There are several mistakes here.

> I have used Kepler's 3rd law to calculate the Semi-Major axis ...

Of what? You have not shown your calculations.

> 1 SOLAR MASS

Do not use the product of the Newtonian gravitational constant and the mass of some solar system body. You might well run into a consistency problem. This happens frequently with WolframAlpha as it definitely has inconsistent values. Instead, use the gravitational mass parameter. This  conceptually is the product of a body's mass and the Newtonian gravitational constant. In practice, the mass of a solar system body is instead computed from its gravitational mass parameter divided by the Newtonian gravitational constant. The reason is that the gravitational mass parameter of the Sun is known to about eleven decimal places of accuracy, while the Newtonian gravitational constant is only known to about five places.

> 365 days, 6 hours, 9 minutes

A better figure is 365 days, 6 hours, 9 minutes, and 56 seconds because that's how the astronomical unit was formerly defined. The former definition of the astronomical unit was the semi major axis of an unperturbed test mass that orbits the Sun with a mean motion of exactly 0.01720209895 radians per day. Dividing $2\pi$ radians by 0.01720209895 radians per days yields 365 days, 6 hours, 9 minutes, and 56 seconds. That missed 56 seconds (almost a minute) is a cause of some amount of error.

> 1.0000001124 AU - 92.95 million miles

There are multiple problems just with this. One is expecting the difference between two nearly equal numbers, one with ten places of precision and the other with four places of precision to have any accuracy at all. Another issue is the 92.95 million miles. The astronomical unit is now defined as exactly 149597870.7 km, or about 92.955807273 million miles.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing Semi-Axis calculation of the Earth